# how long can a rails active job be delayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, jobs, rails-activejob

Just wondering how long can a rails active job be delayed?

Currently I'm delaying some jobs for days and sometimes weeks, is that fine or is there a risk that it won't get executed in the end?

I'm currently using heroku and restarting my server every 6 hours, could that affect my jobs and sidekiq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which Active Job adapter you're using: some don't support delays at all, some have time limits, some will accept any value but get forgotten if the process restarts, and some (most) use persistent storage so that any delay is fine. Sidekiq is in the latter category: restarts will not cause problems (as long as your server is running -- Heroku stops hobby-size sites when they're inactive, and scheduled jobs don't count).

The only risk to be aware of is that jobs will be scheduled using the parameters you pass when you schedule them, and run using the code that's current when they come due: with longer delays, you need to be more careful about changing the number [or meaning] of parameters.

Comment: awesome thanks for the detailed explanation as I could not find the info anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I should be fine, because it is you redis db that records/keeps the date when to execute the job.